# What is the target operand of MIPS j & beq instructions represent?

Tags: mips

Could you please tell me what is the target operand of the following two MIPS instructions represent:

```
j target  
beq $t0,$t1,target
```

is target represent the number of instructions displacement or bytes displacement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In assembly, the target is just a label of your source code.
When assembled, `j` jumps unconditionally to the effective address encoded by the **instruction * 4**. This is due to the fact that every instruction occupies 4 bytes, and each instruction must be word-aligned, so the encoding of the instruction does not store the two less significant bits of the target address (which will be always 00).

The branch instructions performs a relative jump. In machine code, the instruction stores (in A2-compliment) the number of words to move counting from the address of the next instruction to be executed.

In your jargon, they both be 'instructions displacement'.